# How to enable text color in vim?

Tags: linux, shell, vim

I have a file that I report to daily using shell script. There are also colored texts in this report.

Normally, when the file is executed, color text is displayed, but when the result is saved to a log file and the log file is opened by Vim, the color code is displayed instead of the color.

I have no access to install any packages on the Linux!

I want write colorful into file, I tried to find the answer but haven't found it yet!

## Input 1 :

```
green=`tput setaf 2`
reset=`tput sgr0` 
echo -e "\n====== ${green}Instance Status${reset} ======\n"
```

## Output 1 : file opened in Vim:

====== ^[[32mInstance Status^[(B^[[m ======

## OR

## Input 2 :

```
  if [ -t 1 ] ; then
    green=$'\x1b\x5b32m'   
    reset=$'\x1b\x5b0m'   
else 
    green=
    reset=
fi   
echo -e "\n====== ${green}Instance Status${reset} ======\n"
```

## Output 2 : file opened in Vim:

====== Instance Status ======

Comment: You're looking for [AnsiEsc](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=302), it requires you to download and install an extension though

Comment: I have no access to install any packages on the Linux!

Comment: You don't need any special access to install vim packages in your own account.

Answer (score 1):

You should change the exporter script to use color codes only when the output goes to a terminal:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -t 1 ] ; then
    color_red=$'\x1b\x5b31m'
    color_green=$'\x1b\x5b32m'
    # ... 
    color_end=$'\x1b\x5b0m'
else
    color_red=
    color_green=
    color_end=
fi

echo "${color_green}Success${color_end} foo"
echo "${color_red}Error${color_end} bar"
```

When the output goes to a terminal it's colored, when you write to a file it's not colored:

```
bash script.sh # colored
bash script.sh > foo.txt
cat foo.txt # not colored
```

Comment: Thanks but I want write colorful into file